# Getting the individual details

Tags: jquery

**form:**

```
<label>First Name:</label><input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname">
<label>Last Name:</label><input type="name" class="form-control" id="lname">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</button>
```

I am adding the first name and last name into the table if i click on add button.

**table:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
    <thead><tr><td>S.N.</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Options</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    var i=0;
    $(document).on('click', '#add', function (e) 
    { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var fname=$('#fname').val();
        var lname=$('#lname').val();
        if(fname=='' || lname=='')
        {
            swal('Both fields are required!');
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            $('#tbody').append('<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>'+fname+'</td><td>'+lname+'</td><td><button id="view" class="btn btn-info">Details</button></td></tr>');
            $('#showf').append(fname);
            $('#showl').append(lname);
        }

        document.getElementById('fname').value = "";
        document.getElementById('lname').value = "";
    });
});
```

Now, I need to show respective first name and last name if I click on details.

```
$(document).on('click', '#view', function (e) {
    swal('I am trying. ...');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following. You are duplicating the id `#view` use class `view` instead.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.view', function(e) {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var firstName = tr.find('td').eq(1).text();
    var lastName = tr.find('td').eq(2).text();
    alert(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
    <thead><tr><td>S.N.</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Options</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>fname</td>
            <td>lname</td>
            <td><button class="view btn btn-info">Details</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>fname 2</td>
            <td>lname 2</td>
            <td><button class="view btn btn-info">Details</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `tr.find('td').eq(1).text();` little expalnation on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `find('td')` will get the all `td` under `tr` and `eq` will get the `td` of specified index. [See this](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) @Steve